# scripts marging in php

Tags: php

It must be possible to marge two or more scripts together. But i don't know how can be it possible.
as an example :

```
<?php
// here links of POST/GET action for if else. Users can choice here

if (action 1 ){
// first script 
echo "first Test";
}
if (action 2){
//second scripts
echo "second test";
}

?>
```

It can be possible by `if-else with POST/GET`  .

But in many scripts like wordpress login panel script, there are no `POST/GET` option. only link option. Which is an internal link. like :

```
wp-login.php        //main script
wp-login.php?action=lostpassword       //internal script
```

How can i do this with my example script ? Any solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$action = null;
if(array_key_exists('action', $_REQUEST)) {
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
}

switch($action) {
    case 'lostpassword':
        //dothis;
        echo 'first Test';
        break;
    case 'dothat':
        //dothat;
        break;
    case 'doda':
        //doda;
        break;
    default:
        //other actions!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<?php

if ($_GET['action'] == 'lostpassword') {
    echo 'you have lost your password';
}

if ($_GET['action'] == 'login') {
    echo 'logging you in';
}

?>
```

Or:

```
<?php

if ($_GET['action'] == '1') {
    echo "first Test";
}

if ($_GET['action'] == '2') {
    echo "second test";
}

?>
```

Basically if you were to visit `doc.php?action=lostpassword`, "you have lost your password" would be the output, but if you visited `doc.php?action=login`, "logging you in" would be the output.

Comment: So, i have to make  `GET` options ? 
And  links like :  `http://doc.php?action=lostpassword`  . And in `GET` option's action field add this link ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question, which options are you talking about?

Comment: Is it possible that, i won't use any if function. When someone click the internal link `i:e doc.php?action=lostpassword` then it will work with `lostpassword` script ?

Comment: The other way would be to use a break statement, as @silly mentioned. I believe you're looking for an if statement, because they are easier to understand. I've added a version to my answer, which should be what you're looking for.

Comment: i found those two answer is same.